# Interactive Timetable in C# (for parental control)

Tags: c#

Hello fellow stackoverflow users!
Currently I'm working on an application with the goal to limit ones PC usage (as shown in the following image): [Windows Parental Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn80c.png)
So the problem isn't exactly the functionality, but more visualizing and making the timetable interactive so you can set time periods of different days in which the device may be accessed for set amount of time.
I've already tried working with a DataTable but that doesn't seem to give me appropriate results in terms of a user interface you can actually interact with. 
Does anyone have a suggestion on which type of WinForm element to use or any external libraries that could make for a similar look ([Windows Parental Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn80c.png))
Thanks for your time and I look forwards to your answers! :)

Comment: you can start defining an usercontrol.

Comment: @LeiYang Thanks for the suggestion! I'm afraid I'm unfortunately not too proficient at C# so just "defining an usercontrol" seems like a hard task to tackle.

Comment: if you search there's plenty of resources to start: such as open source [1](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=bettercalendar) [2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30329/Creating-an-Outlook-Calendar-using-WPF-Part-1) commercial [3](https://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/scheduling/schedule#Overview) [4](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=404)

Comment: Okay, I thought there may be a different sort of control other than a calendar but that seems to do it as well. Thanks, I only need personal since this a school project.